# A misunderstanding of V4L2

Tags: c++, linux, v4l2

I have a small problem with the size of my buffers in a C++ program.
I grab YUYV images from a camera using V4L2 (an example is available [here](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) )

I want to take one image and put it into a my own image structure.
Here is the buffer given by the V4L2 structure and its size

```
(uchar*)buffers_[buf.index].start, buf.bytesused
```

In my structure, I create a new buffer (mybuffer) with a size of width*height*bitSize (byte size is 4 since I grab YUYV or YUV422 images).

The problem is that I was expecting the buffer *buf* to be the same size as the one that I created. But this is not the case, for example when I grab a 640*480 image buf=614400 and mybuffer=1228800 (twice as big).

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case ?

Comment: How do you get 32 bits/pixel out of YUV422?

Comment: YUYV format is 16 bits per pixel because you have two Y, one U and one V for every TWO pixels (U and V are sub-sampled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YUV422** uses **4 bytes** per **2 pixels**

In **YUV422** mode the `U` ans `V` values are shared between two pixels. The bytes in the Image are ordered like `U0 Y0 V0 Y1 U2 Y2 V2 Y3` etc.

Giving pixels like:

```
pixel 0   U0Y0V0
pixel 1   U0Y1V0
pixel 2   U2Y2V2
pixel 3   U2Y3V2
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but since my buffer's type is unsigned char, how would you represent that fact ? By dividing the size of mybuffer by two when I allocate the memory ?

Comment: Your buffer ought to be 640*480*2 = 614400 bytes, right? That does not change with it being unsigned char. sizeof(char) is required to be 1

Comment: Ok my question was exactly that: because YUV422 -> 4 bytes per 2 pixels is that allowed to write in my code that the number of channels for this format is 2 (and not 4) ?