# stereo Camera OpenCV read depth image correctly 2 pixels encoded in 1

Tags: c++, image, opencv, depth, stereo-3d

I have a stereo camera that gives  an image in the format YUYV with a a resolution of 320 x 480, where in each pixel (16 bits) has encoded 2 pixels of 8 bits. I'm using OpenCV in order to get the image but when I try to get the real resolution of the image I wont get good results. I guess I missing how to properly split the 16 bits in two.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379341/a-misunderstanding-of-v4l2?rq=1) and [this](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/V4L2-PIX-FMT-YUYV.html) I'm able to reconstruct an image but still is not the real one.

```
Mat frame;
unsigned int width= cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
unsigned int height= cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
m_pDepthImgBuf = (unsigned char*)calloc(width*height*2, sizeof(unsigned char));

...
cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
imshow("YUVY 320x480", frame);
memcpy( (void*)m_pDepthImgBuf, (void*)frame.data, width*height*2 * sizeof(unsigned char) );
cv::Mat depth(height,width*2,CV_8UC1,(void*)m_pDepthImgBuf);
```

camera properties:

**SDL information:**
**Video driver:** x11
Device information:
Device path:  /dev/video2
Stream settings:
**Frame format:** YUYV (MJPG is not supported by device)
**Frame size:**   320x480
**Frame rate:**   30 fps

v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    **Index**       : 0
    **Type**        : Video Capture
    **Pixel Format**: 'YUYV'
    **Name**        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

In the following image you can see in green the initial 320x480 image and in gray scale the depth that I'm trying to extract.
[image]
[image: green part is the initial image and the black part is when a try to extract the real image]

The expected result should be:
[image]

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around? The camera persumably gives you 8-bit channels for compatibility and you should combine those to a 16-bit image? So shouldn't you want `cv::Mat depth(height,width,CV_16UC1,(void*)m_pDepthImgBuf);`?

Comment: No, It will keep the actual resolution. I use luvcview -d /dev/video2 and the resolution is 320x480. It is the green Image, Maybe I will put it separate to show better that is the half width resolution.

Comment: I just don't think a 8-bit depth image makes much sense. And your result with the alternating pattern seems to confirm my suspicion. Are you sure that it's square pixels?

Comment: In fact is a disparity Image, I have the depth table to pass from disparity to Depth, but first I need to get the 8-bit value.

Comment: nevermind, I really don't understand the formats involved or the input/output

Comment: I have a mat 16-bit 320x480 and I want a mat 8-bit 640x480, Thanks for your help just trying to be clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101680/discussion-between-aburbanol-and-petert).